# SQL View returning different results when selected database different

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, rounding

a weird one.

In troubleshooting why a view returns different results when run from different databases in SQLMS, I've pealed it back to this:

```
select  cast((cast(0.31 as numeric(18,2)) - cast(0.31 as numeric(18,2)) * cast(50 as float) / 100) as numeric(18,2))
union
select  cast((cast(0.31 as numeric(18,2)) - cast(0.31 as numeric(18,2)) * cast(50 as numeric(18,2)) / 100) as numeric(18,2))
```

If I pick one database, it returns 0.15 and 0.16, if I pick a different database, it returns 0.16 and 0.16.

The cast statement is rounding down when 50 is cast as float and up when casting as numeric in one database but rounding up for both statements in the other.

Ideas!?

Comment: What is SQLMS?  Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: SQL Management Studio.  I did try and tag t-sql but it wouldn't let me as I'm a noob.

Comment: What versions and compat levels are the two databases using?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is likely the two following terms from the two halves on the union query:

```
cast(50 as float) / 100
cast(50 as numeric(18,2)) / 100
```

The quantity on top is using floating point precision, which is not exact, while the quantity on the bottom is using the numeric type, which is exact.  I don't know the details of your SQL Server versions, but the variations you are seeing are fair game, depending on how the particular version of SQL Server and the underling processor handle the above floating point calculation.

To avoid this uncertainty, you should use numeric or decimal type everywhere.  That is, you should lean towards the bottom version of the calculation.

Comment: Yes I agree and would do if it was my software.

Both dabases are on the same server and the same version.

Comment: MS SQL Server is a program just as any other program.  While the math you showed us appears the same, it doesn't necessarily mean that the calculations would execute in the same part of SQL Server's code.  So, I don't see much reason to change my answer.  Just stick with exact types to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the Compatibility of the database.  Something changed between SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016.

Reducing the Compatibility on the problem database to 2014 from 2016 fixes the issue.

Clearly not mixing data types or at least casting all the fields as the same type is the way forward.